# Unable to add custom message for error message in jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer

This is my code. I want to display custom error message in JWplayer. currently I am displaying a image. How can I achieve custom error messages for different situation in JWplayer. I want to display error messages for different parameters.

```
var videoNode = document.getElementById("videoUrlPath").value;
    var player = jwplayer('play');
    var playerCall = true;
    var seeking = false;
    var currentPosition = 0;
    var jw_selector = "#play";
    player.setup({
        file: videoNode,
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "16:9",
        autostart: true,
        /*advertising: {
             client: 'vast',
             schedule: {
                 adbreak1: {
                     offset: "pre",
                     tag: '/static/assets/vast.xml',
                     'skipoffset': '5'
                      }
                     }
                  },
        "sharing": {
            "sites": ['facebook', 'twitter', 'email'],
            link: ''
        },*/
        skin: {
            name: 'myskin',
            url: 'assets/theme/js/jwplayer-7.8.6/skins/tfcskin.css'
        },
    });
    player.play();
    player.onSetupError(function (error) {
        player.setup({
            file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/7RtXk3vl-52qL9xLP.mp4",
            width: "100%",
            aspectratio: "16:9",
            image: "assets/theme/images/error-video.jpg"
        });
        player.play();
    });
    player.onTime(function (callback) {
        currentPosition = callback.position;
        if (this.getPosition() === this.getDuration() && playerCall) {
            playerCall = false;
            document.getElementById("viewcountincrease").click();
        }
    })
    player.onPlay(function (event) {
        playerCall = true;
    })
    player.onSeek(function () {
        if (!seeking) {
            seeking = true;
            var _currentPosition = currentPosition;
            /* WITH A SMALL DELAY SCROLL BACK */
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var elem = document.querySelector(jw_selector);
                jwplayer(elem).seek(_currentPosition);
            }, 100);
        } else seeking = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would show a custom text error message, you can use a wrap div around your player. 
The onError and onSetupError events returns the error message, you can found error messages list at this page: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403682-common-error-messages

This is a codepen example: 
http://codepen.io/fdambrosio/pen/vmbPEK

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapvideo">
    <div id='player'></div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapvideo {
  width: 544px;
  height: 306px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
#wrapvideo p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("player");
playerInstance.setup({  
    file:'videoNode',   
    width: 544, 
    height: 306, 
});

playerInstance.on('error', function(evt){
    var element = document.getElementById("wrapvideo");
    if (evt.message === "Error loading player: No playable sources found") 
        { element.innerHTML = "<p>Your message</p>"; }
    else { element.innerHTML = "<p>Another message</p>"; }
});

playerInstance.on('setupError', function(evt){
    var element = document.getElementById("wrapvideo");
    if (evt.message === "No suitable players found and fallback disabled") 
       { element.innerHTML = "<p>Your message on setup error</p>"; }
    else { element.innerHTML = "<p>Another message on setup error</p>"; }
});
```

You can do the same thing using and image or video for each different error message